# Is NodeList an array or a list or something else?

Tags: java, performance, dom

I'm writing a presentation on java performance, and I'm trying to determine if this is a bad practice.  Im a c++ guy, so I don't know everything about java just yet.  I don't have the source code for item() and I needed a quick answer!

Is this bad for performance:

```
NodeList elems;  // public abstract interface org.w3c.dom.NodeList 
for (int i = 0; i < elems.getLength(); i++) {
  elem = elems.item(i);
  if (elem.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    // do something with a node
  }
}
```

My first concern is NodeList might be implemented with a linked list in which case item(i) would be a disaster.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Use a `List` initialized as `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`. Do not use this library since it's meant to work with web services.

Comment: Seems like this is a bad library.  What is a good one?

Comment: It's not bad. In fact, it's used internally by Java, it's not meant to be used by programmers directly. What are you trying to show with the usage of this interface?

Comment: I've got handed this code that is iterating through nodes in an xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the implementation. For instance OpenJDK provides a [linked list implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/javax/imageio/metadata/IIOMetadataNode.java#IIOMetadataNode.item%28int%29).

```
public Node item(int index) {
     if (index < 0) {
         return null;
     }

     Node child = getFirstChild();
     while (child != null && index-- > 0) {
         child = child.getNextSibling();
     }
     return child;
 }
```

More precisely, `Node` is an interface. Unlike the `List` interface, its documentation makes no guarantees on performance. The above implementation is `IIOMetadataNode`. This class again makes no performance guarantees in its documentation, but the source is above and answers the question.

There are many implementations:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl
com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DeepNodeListImpl
com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.HelperNodeList
// ...
```

That may make other performance guarantees. You should try to determine the implementing class for the `NodeList` you are dealing with and inspect its source code.

Comment: There are several implementations of this interface. I don't know which one you're looking at.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza it's expanded.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza (and I linked to the source)

Comment: Careful. OP's looking for `public interface org.w3c.dom.NodeList`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza how can you tell?

Comment: First line of code: `NodeList elems;  // public abstract interface org.w3c.dom.NodeList `

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html that's where I started

Comment: And you provide a single implementation for this interface. There are more implementations of it: `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl`, `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DeepNodeListImpl`, `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.HelperNodeList` and on... and all can be found inside rt.jar. The fact this isn't in OpenJDK is just a factor. And I've found implementations of this interface in other libraries like `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl`. Also, the first class mentioned use a `Vector` rather than a linked list for implementation.

Comment: I also like tombrown52's answer, which points out that using this library, this is the only solution.  But this has more detail about an example implementation.  I'm going to choose this answer but I also like tombrown52's extra info.

Answer (score 2):

`NodeList` is an Interface, without knowing which implementation you are/will be using, its not possible to say how it is implemented.

The Interface looks something like this:

```
interface NodeList {
  int getLength();
  Node item(int index);
}
```

[Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html) say:

> The NodeList interface provides the abstraction of an ordered collection of nodes, without defining or constraining how this collection is implemented. NodeList objects in the DOM are live.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. It's more like a comment with lot of text in it.

Answer (score 1):

The WC3 standard stipulates the underlying data structure for a NodeList, so whether it's an array or linked list (or both) would be up to the implementation of the DOM. However, the NodeList interface only defines "getLength()" and "item(i)", so the code you wrote is just about the only way to accomplish your task regardless of performance.

Comment: I like your answer about being the only way.  I also like djechlins details about an actual implementation.  I wish I could accept both answers.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Java Doc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html)

A nodeList is an ordered collection of nodes, thus I would assume that it is a list of sorts. If memory serves me right, an ArrayList uses the logic behind regular arrays under the hood. The reason I suspect it is a list is mainly due to its name "nodeLIST."

As for item(index), it will either return the item at the index or it will return null. Again this comes from the API. Hope this helps, I haven't really used nodeLists much.